# Jenkins pipeline creation through Salesforce CLI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, salesforce, salesforce-cli

I am new to Salesforce.

Can anyone help is it possible to create Jenkins pipeline through Salesforce CLI.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no cli command to create the pipeline if that's what you're asking.
But you can create a pipeline that uses the cli to do deployements etc. Check this for reference https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-jenkins-org